# Email Rejection Validations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, email, email-validation

How to reject Email with multiple .xml attachments

hw to reject Email with ZIP Attachments using

IMAP Configuration in java using jpa,springboot

I am able to read the INBOX and attachments from the email

```
   if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {

       //TODO validate number of XMLs per EMAIL

       Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
       int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
       Set<InvoiceContent> invoiceContents = new HashSet<>();

       for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
           MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
           if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {

               System.out.println("File name:"+part.getFileName());

               if(part.getFileName().endsWith(".xml")){
                   Map<String,String> invoiceDetails = invoiceXmlParser.readXmlData(part.getInputStream());
                   InvoiceContent invoiceContent = mapToInvoice(invoiceDetails, part.getInputStream(), emailContent,
                                        part.getFileName());
                   invoiceContents.add(invoiceContent);
               }
           }
       }
       emailContent.setXmlEntities(invoiceContents);
       emailRepository.save(emailContent);
   }
}
emailFolder.close(false);
store.close();
```